# SCNode doesn't have boundingBox property in Objective-c?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, arkit, bounding-box

I'm trying to correctly position another SCNode and all the examples I find are using the boundingBox property like so:

`let vaseHeight = vaseNode.boundingBox.max.y - vaseNode.boundingBox.min.y`
or
`glassesNode.position.z = faceNode.boundingBox.max.z * 3 / 4`

The problem is that doesn't exist with Objective-c and I can't find anything to replace it?

I was able to find this method

```
- (BOOL)getBoundingBoxMin:(SCNVector3 *)min 
                      max:(SCNVector3 *)max;
```

but it returns a bool and how I can know the min and max, that's what I'm trying to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swift property is returning a tuple. The Objective-C method has two out-parameters.

`getBoundingBoxMin:max:` is the correct method. The two parameters are populated as a result of the call. The `BOOL` return value indicates whether the node has a non-zero volume or not.

```
SCNVector3 min;
SCNVector3 max;
CGFloat vaseHeight;
if ([vaseNode getBoundingBoxMin:&min max:&max]) {
    // Process min and max here
    vaseHeight = max.y - min.y;
} else {
    // Node has a zero volume
    vaseHeight = 0;
}
```